# Embed SSRS 2016 Mobile Report into MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, handler, ssrs-2016

We are trying to embed an SSRS 2016 mobile report into our MVC Application.
We attempted to implement a "Reverse Proxy using HTTP Handler while SSRS authentication is set to basic".

The reason behind the use of Basic Authentication is that not all users that are accessing this page have NTLM access.
In the rsreportserver.config we set the Authentication to be as follows:

```
<Authentication>
    <AuthenticationTypes>
       <RSWindowsBasic> 
           <LogonMethod>3</LogonMethod>
           <Realm></Realm>
           <DefaultDomain>workgroup</DefaultDomain>
       </RSWindowsBasic>
    </AuthenticationTypes>        
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
    <RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
    <EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
</Authentication>
```

So in general the link that is being redirected to within our page is partitioned as : //AppServer/KEYWORD/ReportPath
In the codebehind we are setting the handlers not only for KEYWORD but also for the elements within the page like assests and api. Such that we are getting the entire content of the mobile report

(//Server/ReportS/mobilereport/ReportPath) and writing it to our OutputStream. 
Within the handler the authentication header for the request is being set.

The issue is that OAuth.js keeps failing with net: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.
And we are never redirected to that specific report but to the homepage even if rs:Embed=true is included in the URL.

Why is it constantly failing?
And how can I directly load the report?

Code snippet from Handler:

```
     public void Process(HttpContext context)  {
            HttpResponse    response            =  context.Response;
            string  uri                         = "value";
            HttpWebRequest webRequest           = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri));
            webRequest.Method                   = context.Request.HttpMethod;
            webRequest.ImpersonationLevel       = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
            string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
            HttpWebResponse serverResponse      = null;
            try  {
                serverResponse                  = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            }
            catch (WebException webExc)
            {
                response.StatusCode             = 500;
                response.StatusDescription      = webExc.Status.ToString();
                response.End();
                return;
            }
            response.ContentType                = serverResponse.ContentType;
            const   int     blockSize           = 2048;
            byte[]  contentBlock                = new byte[blockSize];
            long    bytesToRead                 = serverResponse.ContentLength;
            Stream  dataStream                  = serverResponse.GetResponseStream();

           while (bytesToRead > 0)   {
                int     blockToRead             = (int)Math.Min(blockSize, bytesToRead);
                int     bytesRead               = dataStream.Read(contentBlock, 0, blockToRead);
                bytesToRead                     -= bytesRead;
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(contentBlock, 0, bytesRead);
            }                       
            serverResponse.Close();            
            context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
            context.Response.End();
      }
```

Note: We are using this handler cause we are aware that the report-viewer does not cater to mobile reports

Comment: Do you have any images that are not embedded on the report such as an image reference to a location that the user does not have access to?

Comment: @RossBush Nope, all I used are the actual report elements with the default data, that comes with them, as a prototype to get my above goal to work.